# Transient cancellation in non causal filtering

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response

I am using the exponential moving average filter (IIR): 
$$y(n)=\alpha{}\cdot{}x(n)+(1-\alpha{})y(n-1)$$
in a foward-backward filtering scheme, in order to eliminate completely any phase response phenomena. But I do not know how to eliminate the startup transients, ie. the transients from the initial state of the filter before and after the duration of the data.

Can you help me please?

I have in mind the Gustafsson's paper, but I found it a bit messy...

Comment: Why don't you use a linear phase FIR filter instead?

Comment: FIR filters are not my choice. For example a moving average of 10 points discards ten points from my data. And they do not have a phase response equal to zero.

Comment: OK, but with offline processing - which you have to do anyway with the filtfilt approach - you can get zero phase with a linear phase FIR filter of odd length $N$. Just shift the output to the left by $(N-1)/2$ and you have a zero-phase filter.

Comment: Yes but I will lose (N-1)/2 points from the end. As you can see, the end of the data is important to me. The application is by definition offline, but I will use it for online applications with a fairly low datarate. So I am seeking a method to separate the transient from the end of the filtered data. Anyway, thank you for your interest.

Comment: BTW, @MattL., with the Powell-Chau technique, you can using the filtfilt() approach, process "on line" (or in real time).  (and it appears to me that jojo wants his/her cake and to eat it too.)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Oh yes, they found some way to implement linear-phase IIR filters, didn't they? Just completely forgot how it works. Must be reversing small sections ...

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson:You are right. I want these corrections for a trading algorithm ... Is it bad?